# Make node size dependable of other nodes

Tags: tikz-pgf

I use Tikz to draw the following diagram:

[image]

Here is the code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[rounded corners=2pt,inner sep=5pt,node distance=.8cm]
\node [draw](chapter1) {\textit{Chapter 1}};
\node [draw,right=of chapter1] (paper1) {\textit{Paper 1}};

\node [draw, below=of chapter1](chapter2) {\textit{Chapter 2}};
\node [draw,right=of chapter2] (paper2) {\textit{Paper 2}};

\node [draw, below=of chapter2](chapter3) {\textit{Chapter 3}};
\node [draw,right=of chapter3] (paper3) {\textit{Paper 3}};
\node [draw,below=of paper3] (paper4) {\textit{Paper 4}};

\draw [-] (chapter1) -- (paper1);
\draw [-] (chapter2) -- (paper2);
\draw [-] (chapter3) -- (paper3);
\draw [-] (chapter3) -- (paper4);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

What I actually want is to make the height of the chapter3 node so big that the upper top is aligned with paper3 (as it is right now) and the bottom is aligned with paper 4 (that is not yet the case).

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 7):

If you can place the `paper` nodes first, then you can use the `let` syntax to calculate the distance from the top of `paper3` to the bottom of `paper4` and use this as the node height. The width of the line must be subtracted as well.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,calc}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[rounded corners=2pt,inner sep=5pt,node distance=.8cm]
\node [draw](chapter1) {\textit{Chapter 1}};
\node [draw,right=of chapter1] (paper1) {\textit{Paper 1}};

\node [draw, below=of chapter1](chapter2) {\textit{Chapter 2}};
\node [draw,right=of chapter2] (paper2) {\textit{Paper 2}};

\node [draw,below=of paper2] (paper3) {\textit{Paper 3}};
\node [draw,below=of paper3] (paper4) {\textit{Paper 4}};

\path let
  \p1=(paper2.north), \p2=(paper3.south), \n1 = {\y1-\y2-\pgflinewidth}
  in
  node [draw, below=of chapter2,minimum height=\n1](chapter3) {\textit{Chapter 3}};

\draw [-] (chapter1) -- (paper1);
\draw [-] (chapter2) -- (paper2);
\draw [-] (paper3 -| chapter3.east) -- (paper3);
\draw [-] (paper4 -| chapter3.east) -- (paper4);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

One option could be to draw nodes `paper3` and `paper4` before `chapter3` and use both to set `chapter3` node size with `fit` library help:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning, fit}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[rounded corners=2pt,inner sep=5pt,node distance=.8cm]
\node [draw](chapter1) {\textit{Chapter 1}};
\node [draw,right=of chapter1] (paper1) {\textit{Paper 1}};

\node [draw, below=of chapter1](chapter2) {\textit{Chapter 2}};
\node [draw,right=of chapter2] (paper2) {\textit{Paper 2}};

\node [draw,below=of paper2] (paper3) {\textit{Paper 3}};
\node [draw,below=of paper3] (paper4) {\textit{Paper 4}};

\node [draw, inner sep=0pt, fit=(paper3.north-|chapter2.west) (paper4.south-|chapter2.east), label=center:\textit{Chapter 3}, below=of chapter2](chapter3) {};

\draw [-] (chapter1) -- (paper1);
\draw [-] (chapter2) -- (paper2);
\draw [-] (chapter3.east|-paper3) -- (paper3);
\draw [-] (chapter3.east|-paper4) -- (paper4);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Here is the brute force appled:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,calc}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[font=\itshape,rounded corners=2pt,inner sep=5pt,node distance=.8cm]
\node [draw](chapter1) {Chapter 1};
\node [draw,right=of chapter1] (paper1) {Paper 1};

\node [draw, below=of chapter1](chapter2) {Chapter 2};
\node [draw,right=of chapter2] (paper2) {Paper 2};


\node [draw,below=of paper2] (paper3) {Paper 3};
\node [draw,below=of paper3] (paper4) {Paper 4};

%% define a coordinate between paper 3 and paper 4.
\coordinate (p34) at ($(paper3)!0.5!(paper4)$);

% put the node chapter3 at this mid point, don't draw the border.
\node (chapter3) at (chapter2|- p34) {Chapter 3};

% draw the border.
\draw (chapter2.west|-paper4.south) rectangle (chapter2.east|-paper3.north);

\draw [-] (chapter1) -- (paper1);
\draw [-] (chapter2) -- (paper2);
\draw [-,rounded corners=0pt] (chapter3.east) |- (paper3);
\draw [-,rounded corners=0pt] (chapter3.east) |- (paper4);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]